# removing duplicates with tail

Tags: sort, tail

How can I remove duplicate in `tail` output?

I'm using `tail -f file.txt | sort file.txt | uniq`

it stops `tail` after some sec

Comment: Are you trying to apply `sort` and `uniq` to the output of `tail -f`?  Right now `sort` won't be using the `tail` at all so I'm not sure why it's in a pipeline with it

Comment: yes i want `tail` output like `sort | uniq `

Comment: Do you need '-f' option in tail?

Comment: If '-f' is not needed, *tail file.txt | sort | uniq* would do

Comment: or even `tail -n 100 | sort -u`

Comment: you can not expect to sort an output stream, which is constantly updating. Otherwise, what is is going to sort against ?

Comment: `watch -n 1 sort file.txt | uniq` not work

Answer (score 7):

With `tail -f`, the `sort` will keep waiting, because it wants to sort *the whole file*, which will never happen. If you want to remove all duplicate lines ever (so there's just one occurance), you'll need something more sophisticated. If you just want to remove duplicates that are one after another, leave off the sort and just do `tail -f | uniq`.

Comment: `sort file.txt | uniq`  how can i run it continually ?

Comment: seems `watch` can help me , but  `watch -n 1 sort file.txt | uniq` not work

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi I don't understand what you expect the output to look like. Since the output will be a stream, the sort command can't go _back_ and insert new items before previous ones. It has to wait for all of the input. You just plain can't use `sort` in this way.

Comment: @mattdm - +1. `tail -f | uniq` is probably the best that can be done.  It's worth noting that if the file being tailed has a timestamp in the first N fields (N=3 is common for many log files), you can tell `uniq` to skip the first 3 fields with `tail logfile | uniq -f 3`.  This allows dupe detection even when the timestamp changes.

Comment: not work , also `watch -n 1 sort file.txt | uniq` not worked .

Comment: @Mehran Please see my comment above. What do you expect working to look like?

Comment: @mattdm i just want see live update my logfile and  also remove duplicate , like `sort file | uniq ` command

Comment: @Mehran Please, please answer this question: do you mean duplicate lines in a row, or do you mean if a line occurs once, you never want to ever see it again?

Comment: And, second, do you actually want the output *sorted*, or is that just the way you know to remove duplicates?